# Customize selecting dependency version

Tags: gradle

in my project dependency which I'm using has many similar version names, eg: 1.0.0, 1.0.0-dev, 1.0.0-dev2... Is there a way to list all versions starting with 1.0.0 and select interesting version from that list? 
I was thinking about resolutionStrategy, but it doesn't contain list of possible versions

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
configurations.all.resolutionStrategy {
    List<DependencyResolveDetails> drdList = []
    eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'foo' && details.requested.name = 'bar') {
            drdList << details
        } 
    }
    if (drdList.size() > 1) {
        List<String> versionOptions = drdList*.requested*.version
        String selectedVersion = selectBestVersion(versionOptions) // TODO: implement
        drdList.each { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.version != selectedVersion) {
                details.useVersion(selectedVersion).because("I picked $selectedVersion using a custom strategy")
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Perhaps you could create a plugin for this so that applying a custom strategy for a group/name is a bit cleaner possibly by registering a `Comparator<String>` for a group/name combination

Eg:

```
apply plugin: 'x.y.custom-version-strategy'

Comparator<String> customVersionComparator = (String version1, String version2) -> { ... }
customVersionStrategy {
     strategy 'foo', 'bar', customVersionComparator
}
```

Comment: I would like to hane dependency like this:
dependencies { foo:bar:1.0.+}
and I would like to receive all matching versions and select one from them, but above solution will return only one version, which will be 1.0.+. 
Sorry, I didn't precise my question at the begining

Comment: yuck, dynamic version ranges.... why on earth would you want to do that

Comment: Because it's project which gathers dependency jars. It should take latest version, unfortunately on repository lands not only released jars, but jars with suffixes which should be excluded from build. That's why I'm asking. I know this is not perfect solution, but for this case dynamic ranges are quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, that finnaly I have found a solution:

```
configurations.all{
    resolutionStrategy {
        componentSelection {
            all { ComponentSelection selection ->
                if(notInteresting(selection.candidate.version))
                   selection.reject("")
            }
        }
    } 
}
```